# How to add a video that fit to a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
     <div class="box1">
        <video   preload="auto" autoplay loop muted="muted" volume="0"> 
        <source src="videos/splash4.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
        </video>
        </div>

**This is the css**

.box1{
width:100%;
height:800px;
}
```

So how to make this video fit to the **Div**? like http://www.google.com/nexus/7/

Comment: Have you try this?: `.box1 video { width: 100% !important }`

Answer (score 5):

may be you could just do css, like:

```
video {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.box1 video{ 
   width: 100% !important;
   height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
 <div class="box1">
        <video width=100%  preload="auto" autoplay loop muted="muted" volume="0"> 
            <source src="videos/splash4.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
        </video>
 </div>
```

CSS :

```
.box1{
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
}
```